# How to resize div width with javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to resize the pagewrapper div with javascript. I have chrome and would like to use it as userscript. Here is the site link: http://clanbase.ggl.com. I want to take the pagewrapper to 100% width. I have the following code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://clanbase.ggl.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function addJQuery(callback) {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
script.addEventListener('load', function() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
document.body.appendChild(script);
}, false);
document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function pagewrapper() {
document.getElementById('pagewrapper').style.Width = "100%";
}

addJQuery(pagewrapper);
```

Comment: Consider changing tags here from [tag:java] to [tag:javascript]. They are quite different programming languages. Edit: never mind, I'll do it for you!

Comment: I believe, `width` needs to start with lowercase `w`.  In addition, if you're already loading jQuery, why not just do `$('#pagewrapper').css('width','100%');`?

Comment: Also, you'll want to wrap that in the in the domready or load event, so $(document).ready(pagewrapper);

Comment: Sorry but I'm not javascript coder I found some scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to note is that non-absolutely positioned divider elements automatically take up 100% of the width, so you might not need to do anything. Just try removing the width property from the `pagewrapper` element (in the CSS) and see if it works. You could also try overriding the width property:

```
#pagewrapper {
    width:100%;
}
```

If setting CSS isn't an option for whatever reason, this script should suffice:

```
function pagewrapper() {
    document.getElementById('pagewrapper').style.width = "100%";
}
```